# Product Category page showing all products

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic

Our WP system uses the following plugins:

- WooCommerce `v3.4.4`
- WooCommerce Stock Manager `v1.2.6`
- Display Productfor WooCommerce `v2.0.19`
- Sorting WooCommerce Pro `v4.0`
- Salient Theme `v7.0.8`
- Salient Visual Composer `v4.11.2`

Following a migration, the product category web pages no longer work correctly. They show all products instead of those from the selected category. Also, the filter/sorter has appeared below the header. However, the products show the correct categories in admin.

How would I best debug this issue?

I can output the SQL that selects the category name using print `$wp_query->request;` in the `page.php` template, but how can I debug the product selection that references the category, please?

Comment: I think the product data looks ok, I've checked it with the following Sql: SELECT p.ID as product_id, p.post_title as product_name, p.post_status, t.term_id as cat_id, t.name as category_name
FROM wp_posts as p
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rs ON (rs.object_id = p.ID) 
LEFT JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt ON (rs.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)
LEFT JOIN wp_terms t ON (tt.term_id = t.term_id)
WHERE  (p.post_type = "product" or p.post_type = "product_variation")
AND tt.taxonomy = "product_cat"
AND  p.post_status <> "closed"

Comment: I've compared the difference between the options table for the site that works and the one that doesn't. I notice some differences for the option values  for option_name 'salient_redux', but they only look like difference in id values eg s:86: compared to s:87: for image urls in the uploads directory.

Answer (score 0):

I found there were 195 dp_* settings missing the correct settings in the ‘wp_postmeta’ table, once they were replaced it worked. I assume they were lost during the migration.